# How prove this $\sum_{k+j=n,0\le k,j\le n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2j}{j}=4^n$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Show that
$$
\sum_{k\ +\ j\ =\ n\atop{\vphantom{\LARGE A}0\ \le\ k,\phantom{A}
j\ \le\ n}}{2k \choose k}{2j \choose j} = 4^{n}
$$

I think use integral solve it. But I don't it,and this problem is
[from this](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/a643e6c26137ee06eff91855.html).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}x^k=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}},$
$$\begin{align}\sum_{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k=n,0\le a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k\le n}\binom{2a_1}{a_1}\binom{2a_2}{a_2}\cdots\binom{2a_k}{a_k}\qquad(\star)\end{align}$$
is the coefficient of $x^n$ when we use power series expansion for 
$$\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}\right)^k=(1-4x)^{-\frac 12 k}.$$

Hence, noting that 
$$(1-4x)^{-\frac 12 k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac 12k}{n}(-4x)^{n},$$
we get
$$(\star)=\binom{-\frac 12 k}{n}(-4)^n=\frac{\left(-\frac 12 k\right)\left(-\frac 12 k-1\right)\left(-\frac 12 k-n+1\right)}{n!}\cdot (-4)^n=\frac{\left(\frac 12 k\right)\left(\frac 12 k+1\right)\left(\frac 12 k+n-1\right)}{n!}\cdot 4^n.$$

This can be represented as the following for $m\in\mathbb N$ :

$$(\star)=\binom{m+n-1}{n}\cdot 4^n$$ when $k=2m.$

$$(\star)=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\binom{2m+2n-2}{2n}}{\binom{m+n-1}{n}}$$ when $k=2m-1.$

Your question is the $k=2$ case.